# What is the clearest way to describe two "kitty-corner" buildings?

Tags: expressions

How can I explain the relationship of building A to building B where building A is, e.g., on the NW corner of an intersection, and building B is on the SE corner?

Which of the following (if any) is the clearest?  If none, is there a clearer way?

> The building A would be diagonally opposite the building B.
>
> The building A would be opposite the building B, with 45 degrees to the right.
>
> The building A would be kitty-corner to the building B.

Comment: Kind of ironic, but... I do not understand the question.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: I try to point out the place which is "Not exactly" opposite the street but it's like corner to corner. Just wanna ask which one is common way to say from above three sentences. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It really depends on where the buildings are actually located and what lies between them.  As stated, the question cannot be definitively answered.

Comment: Do the buildings lie on diagonally opposite corners of an intersection (e.g, one on the NW corner, and one on the SE corner) or do the buildings lie on the opposite corners of a square or mall? or do the buildings lie along a straight stretch of road, one on either side, but not directly across from each other?

Comment: They lie on diagonally opposite to each other in the crossroad. Could you tell me the simple way not like diagonally ....so on and so forth?

Comment: What’s wrong with just saying one is kitty-corner to the other?

Comment: "Diagonally opposite" would seem to be appropriate.

Comment: Do non-Americans understand kitty-corner? I'd use "diagonally opposite" in any formal writing.

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm non-American and I've never heard *kitty-corner* before and never would have guessed.

Comment: @PeterShor I endorse Hugo's comment. I think I had heard the express *kitty-corner* but had no idea what it meant and certainly would never have guessed.

Comment: I've always heard them called *diametrically opposed*, but that seems to be [uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diametrically+opposed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiametrically%20opposed%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: and here I always thought it was "caddy-corner" I guess that's just how the dialect in my region was...

Answer (score 7):

Both *kitty-corner* and *catty-corner* are corruptions of *cater-corner* (or *catercorner*); they are often used by people who indeed have never heard of the original expression. Others will have heard of the original expression and regard the corruptions as ignorant vulgarisms; still others will find them acceptable, albeit very informal. My own experience in giving directions to my building is that quite a lot of people even in the United States are not familiar with any of the words, and I have therefore resorted to saying *diagonally opposite from* or *diagonally across from* when I want my meaning to be understood at once. When I am hoping for a chance to give expression to my native didacticism, I say *cater-corner*.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anybody ***say*** "catercorner", even though that seems to be the etymological origin of the phrase. I have heard both "catty-corner" and "kitty-corner". (On the other hand, if the proper pronunciation of "catercorner" is "cat-a-corner", as  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitty-corner) seems to indicate, I may be wrong about this—I might easily not notice the difference between "catty" and "cat-a".)

Comment: The OED has citations with spellings that show it's been pronounced *cattercorner* or *cattycorner* since the early 19th century in the U.S. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cater-cornered?q=catercorner) has the British pronunciation as *Kate-er-corner*, but I have never heard the first syllable pronounced *Kate*, and since they also say it's a North American word, I don't know where they get their British pronunciation from.

Comment: This answer should be prefaced with "In many forms of American English..."

Comment: The OED doesn't have an entry for *kitty-corner*; however, under *rue* v.1 it has the citation *Wilson had rued the hoodlum motorcyclists and snowmobilers cutting **kitty-corner** across his yard and ruining his ferns.* This would be motivation for including it under *cater-cornered*

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are asking about a situation like this:

[image: Buildings Diagram]

It is technically and mathematically correct to say that they are on **opposite corners**.  However, this can indeed be misconstrued, as you've noted.  I do not believe that there are any terms in common usage that would be guaranteed to be clear to any given audience.

Comment: See the earlier comment: *"Diagonally opposite" would seem to be appropriate. – David Aldridge Apr 19 '13 at 8:33*

Answer (score 3):

If the buildings are diagonally across an intersection, *kitty-corner* has exactly the right connotation, but it should be clear even when talking about a single street. From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kitty-corner):

> (US, Canada) (with to:) located diagonally across from something, especially across an intersection

Comment: Gosh, I lived in the US for ten years and never heard the expression "kitty-corner". It would certainly not be familiar to a British reader.

Comment: I can confirm, *kitty-corner* is totally unfamiliar to a British reader.

Comment: It's usually spelled "catercorner", but I don't believe I've ever heard it pronounced any way other than "kitty corner" or "catty corner".

Comment: I don't think *kitty corner* would be familiar to many Australians either.

Answer (score 0):

I was born and raised in St Louis, Missouri and we invariably said "catercorner" (or "cat-a-corner"), but never "kittycorner," which was thought to be a bit silly. But I hear it every day in my new home of Chicago. My point: this is one of those regional usages which will not be recognizable in places where it isn't used.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I would say **opposing corners** on xyz street.